# Issues passing form data to ASP.Net Core Razor Page Handler Method via Fetch (Error 400)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, routes, fetch-api, razor-pages

I can't seem to get this form data to submit to a handler method I have set up.  I'm using an onlick attribute of a button that is in each row of a table to execute a JS function:

```
function approveRequest(id) {
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', id);

fetch('/Admin/PMC/Recommendations?handler=ApproveAsync', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        console.log('Success:', result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

The Handler method is as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostApproveAsync(string id)
{
await _PocService.ApproveAsync(id);
return new OkResult();
}
```

The catch block error I'm geetting is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at Recommendations:737:44
```

I've tried "/Admin/PMC/Recommendations/ApproveAsync" as well as "/Admin/PMC/Recommendations?handler=OnPostApproveAsync" and "/Admin/PMC/Recommendations/OnPostApproveAsync" for the url, but none of them do much. I've tried removing content-type header, or using a different value for it, also tried out mode: 'same-origin', and credentials: 'same-origin.'  I do have standard routing options enabled for the application in program.cs:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
});
```

Comment: you should probably include the full method code... and comment line 737.  Can't tell what's expecting JSON here... but you are POSTing standard form data, not JSON.

Comment: I've tried posting JSON as well, but same issue. Thing is that it doesn't seem to even get to the handler method - I have a breakpoint in it that's never reached and I get a 400, which suggests to me that the url isn't working as it should?

Comment: Hi @LeviWallach, have you tried the solution that I shared? does it work for you?

Comment: Hi @FeiHan, I didn't see your response somehow until now, but I did basically work around this my just using standard form submissions.  Next time I'm looking at this I'll try out what you suggest and see if it helps.

Comment: `I'll try out what you suggest and see if it helps.` Hoping it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

> can't seem to get this form data to submit to a handler method

To post the form data to page handler, please refer to the following example code:

*add the `__RequestVerificationToken` hidden field being added to Razor page*

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

*JS code*

```
function approveRequest(id) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', id);

    fetch('/Admin/PMC/Recommendations?handler=Approve', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        //...
```

Please note that if you omit [the anti-forgery token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0) from the request, the server will return a 400 Bad Request response.

Besides, we can apply the IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute to the relevant PageModel class to bypass the checks, like below.

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class RecommendationsModel : PageModel
{
    //...
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: For more information about Request Verification in ASP.NET Razor Pages, please check https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification